# Can't get bash "reset" command working from code, yet typing it works

Tags: java, bash, terminal

I'm using VSCode to test, in case it matters, but I have the problem using iTerm as well.

When I run the code, the terminal is left in a state where the cursor does not show, the text is red and you can only see what you typed after pressing return.

My goal is to send the `reset` command from inside the java code.

Important note!, if you type `reset` manually and press enter, it will reset correctly (remember you can't see what you type before the reset happened.

```java
package doeke_p5_terminal_graphics_examples;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Terminal_Commands_SO {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    store_terminal_settings();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            // Note(Doeke): those 3 lines help:
            // restore_terminal_settings();
            // turn_off_all_attributes();
            // show_cursor();
            // Note(Doeke): but I wan't this to work:
            reset();
        }
    });

    System.out.println(ANSI_RED);
    put_into_single_character_mode();
    disable_echo();
    hide_cursor();
    
}

static final public String ANSI_RED = "\u001b[31m";


static public String _terminal_restore_settings;

static public void store_terminal_settings() {
    _terminal_restore_settings = cmd("stty -g < /dev/tty");
}

static public void restore_terminal_settings() {
    assert _terminal_restore_settings != null;
    cmd("stty "+_terminal_restore_settings+" < /dev/tty");
}

static public void put_into_single_character_mode() {
    cmd("stty -icanon min 1 < /dev/tty");
}

static public void disable_echo() {
    cmd("stty -echo < /dev/tty");
}

static public void hide_cursor() {
    cmd("tput civis > /dev/tty");
}

static public void show_cursor() {
    cmd("tput cnorm > /dev/tty");
}

static public void reset() {
    // can't get it to work...
    // cmd("reset");
    // cmd("reset > /dev/tty");
    // exec("bash", "reset");
    exec("bash", "reset > /dev/tty");
    // exec("bash", "reset < /dev/tty");
    // rest
    // aaaaaargggggghhhhhhhhhhh
}


static public void turn_off_all_attributes() {
    cmd("tput sgr0 > /dev/tty");
}

static public String cmd(String args) {
    return exec("sh", "-c", args);
}


static public String exec(String... cmd) {

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Process p;
        
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        
        int c;
        InputStream in = p.getInputStream();

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            bout.write(c);
        }

        in = p.getErrorStream();

        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            bout.write(c);
        }

        p.waitFor();

        String result = new String(bout.toByteArray());
        return result.trim();
    } 
    catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        return null;
    }
    
}

}
```

I'm not interested in hacky solutions where I output commands to set the color to white, enable the cursor, enable echo etc. That is not a fix, that is a workaround.

Comment: did you mean to do `bash -c reset` instead of `bash reset`? The later tries to execute a file named "reset" in your working directory.

Comment: Though why you'd run `bash -c reset` instead of just `reset` is confusing to me. `reset` is not part of bash; there's no reason to invoke bash when running it. (Moreover -- you're using `sh` everywhere else; why pull in `bash` here, if you _do_ want a shell?)

Comment: I tried that as well, must have forgot to add it when I isolated the project into a simple runnable example for stackoverflow. I can't get `bash -c reset` to work either.

Comment: First: Where are your Java program's stdin, stdout, and stderr connected? If this is running on a Linux box, `ls -l /proc/PID/fd` is your friend.

Comment: ...part of the goal is to find out if your process even _has_ a controlling TTY at all.

Comment: @Charles Duffy the `cmd` where calling `sh`, but that was not working either. Bash was just another attempt. I did not redirect `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` yet.

Comment: Assuming it _does_ have a controlling TTY: Does it have the `TERM` environment variable correctly set? You can figure that out, again, by reading `/proc/PID/environ`.

Comment: Don't redirect them unless we have to; if they're already pointing to a TTY, then there's no point to redirection.

Comment: **however**, when you call `getErrorStream()`, that increases the chances that we'll need to do some redirection, because it means that at least stderr is pointing to a FIFO with your JVM on the other side, instead of going to the TTY.

Comment: All the other commands do not work without either `> /dev/tty` or `< /dev/tty`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218849/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-clankill3r).